# TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' on undefined Angular2, Ionic 2, InAppBrowser

Tags: angular, ionic2, typeerror, addeventlistener, inappbrowser

I trying to open in my app remote address using cordova pluguin InAppBrowser. I use that code:

```js
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpQueryService } from "./httpqueryservice";
import { ToastController } from "ionic-angular";
import { InAppBrowser, InAppBrowserEvent } from "ionic-native";

/**
 * Класс сервиса для открытия окон в браузере
 */
@Injectable()
export class WindowOpenService {

  inAppBrowserRef: InAppBrowser; //объект с браузером

  /**
   * Конструктор класса
   */
  constructor(
    public toastCtrl: ToastController,
    public httpQueryService: HttpQueryService
  ){

  }

  /**
   * Open url in InAppBrowser
   *
   * @param url
   * @param target
   * @param options
   */
  open(url = 'http://192.168.1.2/myurl/', target = '_blank', options = 'location=yes,hidden=no,hardwareback=yes,toolbar=yes')
  {
    try{
      var inAppBrowserRef = new InAppBrowser(url, target, options);
      inAppBrowserRef.on('loadstart').subscribe((result) => {
        alert(result);
        inAppBrowserRef.close();
      });
      inAppBrowserRef.on('mychange').subscribe((result) => {
        alert(result);
        this.inAppBrowserRef.close();
      });
      inAppBrowserRef.on('loadstop').subscribe((result) => {
        alert(result);
        this.inAppBrowserRef.close();
      });
      inAppBrowserRef.on('loaderror').subscribe((result) => {
        alert(result);
        inAppBrowserRef.close();
      });
    }catch(e){
      alert(e);
    }
  }
}
```

And I get an Error on 'loadstart' event:
**TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' on undefined**

I think that all is allright. But it fire the error? What I'm doing wrong?
I use this pluguin https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/inappbrowser/

And test it on emulator and on device with Android 6 version. The same problem.
In config.xml I use that code:

```html
<allow-navigation href="*://192.168.1.2/*"/>
```

And I use the lastest Ionic 2.2.1 version.

Comment: I'm having the same problem but I also have installed the cordova plugin. I still have the same issue. I keep getting the same error. I have shared the code that I'm using [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42114950/not-able-to-attach-event-handler-in-ionic-2-on-inappbrowser?noredirect=1). Hopefully you can help me because I've been stuck at this for days now.

Comment: Do you use the lastest version of Ionic 2?

Comment: May be help https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/cannot-read-property-addeventlistener-of-undefined-using-inappbrowser/77166/7

Comment: Yes, I'm using the latest Ionic version `2.2.1`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I'm do not install pluguin before use the class.

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
```