# Not able to attach event handler in Ionic 2 on InAppBrowser

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, inappbrowser

I'm very new to `Ionic 2` framework and I'm trying to write an app in which I need to open an external URL in an embedded browser (InAppBrowser). I create an InAppBrowser instance and launch the browser. The browser opens and it also opens the link, but I keep getting an error.

```
Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined
```

Here's the code that I'm using:

```
let browser = new InAppBrowser(
    "http://www.google.com",
    "_blank",
    "location=no,hidden=yes",
);
console.log(browser);
browser.on('loadstop').subscribe(
    (res) => {
        // Handle url checking and body parsing here
    },
    (error) => {
        // Handle error here
    }
);
browser.on('deviceready').subscribe(
    (res) => {
        browser.show();
        console.log(res);
    },
    (error) => {
        console.log(error);
    }
);
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I want to check what the url is everytime the browser loads a webpage and if it is the desired web page then parse the body of the browser and then close it.

I'm trying to integrate a payment gateway. So basically I load the payment url in the browser, user makes the payment and the payment gateway redirects the user to my backend url. Now I want to parse what my backend returns and close the browser. Also, that `console.log(browser)` in there does logs an instance of `InAppBrowser`.

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem, kindly let me know if any solution is reached

Comment: May be help https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/cannot-read-property-addeventlistener-of-undefined-using-inappbrowser/77166/7 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42092228/typeerror-cannot-read-property-addeventlistener-on-undefined-angular2-ionic?noredirect=1#comment71479684_42092228

Comment: I removed the `hidden=yes` and removed the `deviceready` event and it started working. I didn't realize that `deviceready` is not an actual event, also when we create an instance of the browser it automatically launches.